# Images won't load in HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to load an image called ion.png but it won't load. I have it in the same folder as my index.html file. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<img src=“ion.png” width="100" height="80" alt="My Pic">
```

Comment: Try without curly quotes?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use MS Word as your html editor:

```
<img src=“ion.png” width="100" height="80" alt="My Pic">
         ^-------^---
```

Those are not valid quotes. Use `"` or `'`. Not the typographic 6's and 9's.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I didn't even realize those quotes were different

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the right quotes here: `img src=“ion.png”`

It should be `img src="ion.png" width="100" height="80" alt="My Pic"`

Answer (score 0):

Check the file image permissions if you are absolutely sure the path is correct. Ideally you want an image permission of either 644 or 755 (see more information about why at http://forums.cpanel.net/f185/why-644-755-unix-permissions-ideal-files-directories-public-folders-136821.html)

You can change image permissions through ftp, command line, or even on your computer (on mac for example, in the finder, right click the image and go to info)

Hope that helps!